# Android DisplayMetrics returns incorrect screen size in pixels

Tags: java, android, screen, screen-size

I have a Samsung Galaxy S20+.

I run this code:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    mScreenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    mScreenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

I get:

mScreenHeight = 2201.0
mScreenWidth = 1080.0

Whereas the S20+ screen resolution is 1440x3200 according to [this page](https://gadgets.ndtv.com/samsung-galaxy-s20-plus-5g-price-in-india-91460#:%7E:text=The%20phone%20comes%20with%20a,4%20cores%20clocked%20at%202GHz.).

Such a big gap is not just a question of status bar height.

How can I get the real screen size in pixels ?

Thanks !

Comment: you can fetch the current modes supported by display using
context.getDisplay().getMode() to fetch the current display mode. You can also fetch all the supported configurations by context.getDisplay().getSupportedModes() and refer this documentation for more details.
fetching height using this DIsplay.Mode can help you to support for dex mode in your application as starting from R, you will be only getting your application's height and width using displaymetrics.
refer link:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.Mode#getPhysicalHeight()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent Galaxy S devices have a setting to change the screen resolution.
On the S20+ there are 3 options:

- WQHD+: 3200x1440
- FHD+: 2400x1080
- HD+: 1600x720

You're likely in the FHD+ mode. Even though the device has a real pixel dimension of 3200x1440, your usable software window is downscaled and this is what the DisplayMetrics object is giving you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sounds good. Will look at this... Crazy behaviour ideal to induce many bugs on many apps...